# How to calculate variable declared in a method from inside python class function

Tags: python, class

need help about my code (python):

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, money):
        self.money= money
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Money in the bank: {self.money} dollar'
    def withdraw(self,withdraw):
        self.withdraw = withdraw
        money = self.money-self.withdraw
        return money
print(Account.withdraw(20000,1000))
```

What I want from code above is the code will print my remaining money (19000), but I always got error

> 'int' object has no attribute 'withdraw'.

I have tried a lot of things for 4 hours but got no satifying result.

This is my first question in this forum, i am sorry if the formatting is not right.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You are supposed to *instantiate* objects to use them. Just like `mylist = list()` creates a list, you need to create an account object, `account = Account()`. However, note, `account.withdraw(whatever)`  will only work once, because you *shadow* the method `def withdraw` *inside of itself* when you do `self.withdraw = withdraw`, so the second time you withdraw you will get a TypeError, because `int` objects are not callable. Why are you assigning to a `self.withdraw` anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Below I have made some small changes in your code and it is working as you expect.

1. Defined new variable withdrawMoney to track the withdraw amount.
2. Some changes in string format.
3. Returned the updated amount every time.

   ```
   class Account:
     def __init__(self, money):
       self.money= money
       self.withdrawMoney = 0

     def __str__(self):
       return "Money in the bank: {} dollar".format(self.money)

     def withdraw(self,withdrawMoney):
       self.withdrawMoney = withdrawMoney
       self.money = self.money-self.withdrawMoney
       return self.money

   acc = Account(20000)
   print(acc.withdraw(1000)) # 19000
   print(acc.withdraw(1000)) # 18000
   ```